# Unable to POST large html content to server on Chrome

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to send HTML content through a POST request but it is not getting delivered on the server side using Chrome. While I get the request data in my jsp when using Mozilla. 
This works in both browsers when the HTML content is small. I'm generating a PDF with this HTML content using Apache FOP.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('name','eyeframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var myform = document.createElement('form');
document.body.appendChild(myform);
myform.setAttribute('action','myJspToRenderHtmlAsPdf.jsp');
myform.setAttribute('method','post');
myform.setAttribute('target','eyeframe');

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "htmlContent");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", strHTML);
myform.appendChild(hiddenField);
myform.submit();
```

I am dividing the HTML into chunks and posting them and rejoining them in the jsp. This method of doing it also fails with chrome and ie.

Comment: Instead of sent the whole html, send the URL that generate this html. So the server take it and convert to pdf.

Comment: I'm actually generating the HTML text in the javascript itself(XSLT transformation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well inputs in chrome (or maybe whole webkit) has limit of chars - 524288, You can test it by typing in console:

```
var el = document.createElement("input");
el.maxLength
```

Why not use simple [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)?

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("htmlContent", strHTML);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "myJspToRenderHtmlAsPdf.jsp");
request.send(formData);
```

Got some time to write simple demo. Server respons is generated PDF:

```
<a href="#" id="test">Download</a>
<script>

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("htmlContent", 'test');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = 'blob';
request.open("POST", "myJspToRenderHtmlAsPdf.jsp");

request.onload = function(event) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      var blob = new Blob([request.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var link = document.querySelector('#test');
      link.setAttribute('href', url);
    } else {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

request.send(formData, true);
</script>
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest doesn't allow me to download the PDF. That's the reason I was using the elaborate process of creating a dynamic form. Or does it?

Comment: Need a link.click(); in the end to display the pdf.